# How to 'forward' all requests from a group of routes to another, with parameters altering in Symfony2?

Tags: php, rest, symfony, redirect, proxy

I have a RESTful API that is made with Symfony, and secured by OAuth. Here is an example of call:

```
method: POST
url: https://www.mywebsite.com/api/forumposts?access_token=xxxxxxx
params: { title: 'my new post', content: 'this is a great informative new post.' }
```

I would like to implement a sort of proxy (as described [here](http://alexbilbie.com/2014/11/oauth-and-javascript/)) to prevent a client JS app to directly access the API and most importantly to prevent the client OAuth id and secret to be available in the JS code. Here is an example of equivalent call to this proxy:

```
method: POST
url: https://www.mywebsite.com/proxy/forumposts?proxy_key=yyyyyyy
params: { title: 'my new post', content: 'this is a great informative new post.' }
```

What I need is to be able to:

- alter the Request object (for instance replacing `proxy_key=yyyyyyy` by `access_token=xxxxxxx`)
- 'forward' the proxy request to the corresponding route in my base API.

  I do not know if 'forward' is the right word here: what I want is
  the original request to the proxy to be dealt with by Symfony,
  after having modified parameters, as if a direct request to the API.

I guess this will mean creating a Symfony service listening to the `kernel.request` event. But my question is: how should this redirecting service be coded?

NB.

The Symfony Controller `redirect()` function is not to be used here since the redirection must be transparent for the user.

On the other hand, I'd say the Symfony Controller `forward()` function can not be used here either because this function directly calls a Controller and bypass the OAuth checks that would be normally done before and after controller execution when requesting directly the API.